# Python: Write pandas dataframe to google sheets: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have this python file that will write to my Google sheet using the Google 
Sheets API just fine using the code from this example from 
[Python Google API writing to Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46634800/python-google-api-writing-to-)
google-sheet:

```
values = [
    ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date",],
    ["Wheel", "20.50", "4", "3/1/2016",],
    ["Door", "15", "2", "3/15/2016",],
    ["Engine", "100", "1", "30/20/2016",],
    ["Totals", "=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", "=MAX(D2:D4)",],
]
Body = {  
'values' : values,
'majorDimension' : 'ROWS',
}
}
result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
spreadsheetId=spreadsheetID, range=rangeName, 
valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body=Body).execute()  
print("Writing OK!!")
```

However I want to write a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Date    ORCL    TSLA    IBM YELP    MSFT
0   10/24/2016  37.665958   202.759995  145.080612  34.48   59.564964
1   10/25/2016  37.754536   202.339996  145.379303  33.950001   59.555199
2   10/26/2016  37.705326   202.240005  146.275406  33.490002   59.203667
3   10/27/2016  37.616749   204.009995  147.759277  32.740002   58.686134
4   10/28/2016  37.567539   199.970001  147.046234  32.290001   58.461548
5   10/31/2016  37.813587   197.729996  148.086884  32.66   58.510365
246 10/16/2017  48.860001   350.600006  146.830002  43.52   77.650002
247 10/17/2017  49.189999   355.75  146.539993  43.200001   77.589996
248 10/18/2017  49.580002   359.649994  159.529999  44.580002   77.610001
249 10/19/2017  49.349998   351.809998  160.899994  44.439999   77.910004
250 10/20/2017  49.25   345.100006  162.070007  44.52   78.809998
251 10/23/2017  49.310001   337.019989  159.550003  43.599998   78.830002
```

I have tried from here: 
[Appending pandas Data Frame to Google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540827/appending-pandas-data-frame-)
to-google-spreadsheet

```
import gspread
import gc
import pandas as pd
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sh.share('otto@gmail.com', perm_type='user', role='writer')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1C09vB5F8zcyOrY4w_rctVUedXYJCZqtyoTc-bB0bgBY')

sheetName = 'sheet1'
rangeName = "Sheet1!A1:F252"
```

I declared my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

After some processing a non-empty data frame has been created...and 
populated it:

```
    Date    ORCL    TSLA    IBM YELP    MSFT
0   10/24/2016  37.665958   202.759995  145.080612  34.48   59.564964
1   10/25/2016  37.754536   202.339996  145.379303  33.950001   59.555199
2   10/26/2016  37.705326   202.240005  146.275406  33.490002   59.203667
3   10/27/2016  37.616749   204.009995  147.759277  32.740002   58.686134
4   10/28/2016  37.567539   199.970001  147.046234  32.290001   58.461548
5   10/31/2016  37.813587   197.729996  148.086884  32.66   58.510365
246 10/16/2017  48.860001   350.600006  146.830002  43.52   77.650002
247 10/17/2017  49.189999   355.75  146.539993  43.200001   77.589996
248 10/18/2017  49.580002   359.649994  159.529999  44.580002   77.610001
249 10/19/2017  49.349998   351.809998  160.899994  44.439999   77.910004
250 10/20/2017  49.25   345.100006  162.070007  44.52   78.809998
251 10/23/2017  49.310001   337.019989  159.550003  43.599998   78.830002

# Output_conn = gc.open("SheetName").worksheet("xyz")
# Here 'SheetName' is google spreadsheet and 'xyz' is sheet in the workbook

Output_conn = gc.open(sheetName).worksheet(spreadsheetid)

for i,row in df.iterrows():
     Output_conn.append_row(Row)
```

from:  [Appending pandas Data Frame to Google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540827/appending-pandas-data-) frame-to-google-spreadsheet

I have this error msg at this line:

```
Output_conn = gc.open(sheetName).worksheet(spreadsheetid)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'
```

Updated code:

```
import gspread
import gc
import pandas as pd
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sh.share('otto@gmail.com', perm_type='user', role='writer')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1C09vB5F8zcyOrY4w_rctVUedXYJCZqtyoTc-bB0bgBY')
```

Error msg:  UnboundedLocalError: local variable 'sh' referenced before assignment

Any help?  Thanks!

Comment: Where is gc defined? Maybe you are importing the garbage collection module?

Comment: Edit your question to show us what `gc` is.

Comment: Did you read this link? https://github.com/burnash/gspread `gc` is a connection object, you must instantiate it first.

Comment: Thanks COLDSPEED, I read the link.  gspread writes to a sheet in four steps:  import gspread

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

# Open a worksheet from spreadsheet with one shot
wks = gc.open("Where is the money Lebowski?").sheet1

wks.update_acell('B2', "it's down there somewhere, let me take another look.")